# Why is a cv:: Mat object behaving differently between debug and release?

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator, flycapture

I'm having a real head-scratcher of a time trying to figure out why the population of my OpenCV matrix works exactly as I expect it to in debug mode, yet when I try to release the project, it truncates all the values that are given to it, and populates the matrix incorrectly!

A short description of my setup:

- I'm using both the OpenCV and ViSP libraries to work with a USB Flycapture camera.
- I'm running everything on Ubuntu 16.04 in Qt-Creator, since I plan on having a GUI in this project.
- The parameters populating the matrix are important for the calibration of the camera, so the truncation is an absolute no-go!

On to the code!

First, I load the already saved parameters from a file using ViSP's built-in classes. For debugging purposes (and to ensure I wasn't losing my mind,) I also saved the values to global  variables for quick reference:

```
bool load_intrinsics()
{
  vpCameraParameters cam;
  vpXmlParserCaemra parser;
  std::string intrinsicFilePath = "...path to file...";
  std::string cameraName = "Camera";

  if (parser.parse(cam, intrinsicFilePath, camera_name, vpCameraParameters::perspectiveProjWithDistortion) != vpXmlParserCamera::SEQUENCE_OK)
  {
    std::cout << "ERROR WITH LOADING INTRINSICS" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  else
  { // variables here are <double> variables, defined globally
    global_px = cam.get_px();
    global_py = cam.get_py();
    global_u0 = cam.get_u0();
    global_v0 = cam.get_v0();
    global_kud = cam.get_kud();
    return true;
  }
}
```

`

This all works as expected. The function reads all the values correctly and stores those very values (not truncated!) to the global variables.

Next I try to pass those very variables to a `cv::Mat` object, and that's where things start to go down hill...

```
void createCvMat()
{
  //  create camera matrix
  cv::Mat tempCamMat = cv::Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_64F);
  tempCamMat.at<double>(0, 0) = global_px;
  tempCamMat.at<double>(0, 2) = global_u0;
  tempCamMat.at<double>(1, 1) = global_py;
  tempCamMat.at<double>(1, 2) = global_v0;
  tempCamMat.at<double>(2, 2) = 1.0;
  // create distortion matrix
  cv::Mat tempDisMat = cv::Mat::zeros(5, 1, CV_64F);
  tempDisMat.at<double>(0, 0) = global_kud;
  // pass temporary matrices to empty global matrices
  tempCamMat.copyTo(cameraMatrix);
  tempDisMat.copyTo(distortionMatrix);
}
```

Now, as mentioned in the first code-snippit, I've already made sure the global variables have the correct values in them. Yet when I use these matrices to, for example, use `cv::undistort(...)`, it becomes painfully apparent that the matrices did not load properly.

As a sanity-check, I tried to write out the matrices to the console, and make sure the values were being loaded correctly:

```
void sanityCheck(cv::Mat checkMatrix)
{
  std::cout << std::endl << "Matrix holds:" <<std::endl;
  for (int r = 0; r < checkMatrix.rows; r++)
  {
    for (int c = 0; c < checkMatrix.cols; c++)
    {
      std::cout << checkMatrix.at<double>(r, c) << " | ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Calling the sanity check for both matrices in debug mode, I get the following output:

`

```
Camera
Matrix Includes:
606.204 | 0 | 607.664 |
0 | 612.354 | 521.775 |
0 | 0 | 1 |

Distortion
Matrix Includes:
-0.240543 |
0 |
0 |
0 |
0 |
```

`

Note that the `std::cout` console output does truncate the value written to six significant numbers, as the numbers read from the file have nearly twenty significant numbers. Using the `iomanip` library in conjunction with `std::setprecision(...)`, I have confirmed that the full number is properly carried over and inserted into the matrix.

Calling the same function in release, I get the following output:

```
Camera
Matrix Includes:
606 | 0 | 607 |
0 | 612 | 521 |
0 | 0 | 1 |

Distortion
Matrix Includes:
-0 |
0 |
0 |
0 |
0 |
```

`
Note, that even though double variables were passed to a matrix capable of holding double variables, only integer numbers are populating the matrix! For the life in me, I can't figure out why it does this in the release version of the project, but not the debug version!

As a current work-around, I have tried copy-pasta'ing the numbers directly from the "*.xml" file to the  variables as constants, before passing them to the `cv::Mat` object:

```
// define each global variable (don't read from file)
global_px = 606.20444013030078;
...
global_kud = -0.24054321189834804;
// populate matrices
createCvMat();
```

. And this works just fine... I don't know why, but it does.

As any programmer would most likely tell you, this "hard-coding" of constants should be avoided. If I ever change the settings on my camera for whatever reason and have to re-calibrate, or if the end-user wishes to calibrate their own camera, it would be best to simply read these intrinsic values from an external file.

Comment: Looks like a localization issue. E.g. with German localization the decimal "point" is a comma (`,`). Hence, `606.204` will be read as `606` while the `.204` is discarded as not matching the expected format for floating point. Ensure that you activate the "C" locale for whatever you use to read the numbers.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the input! It's true that I'm currently working in Germany, so a localization issue would be quite plausible! However, my entire install, both of the programs and the OS itself, is using the English language with English localization. To reiterate, the program reads the file to variables correctly, but doesn't pass those variables to the ```cv::Mat``` object correctly. That means, writing the double as a constant to the matrix works, but writing the double first to a double variable, then passing that variable to the matrix doesn't!

Comment: I'm used to the fact that any file I/O of std C++ uses locale "C" by default. I don't know what `vpXmlParserCaemra` does. I can remember that I had (a long time ago) a similar issue like you (with XML files as well). In my case, I ended up in the localization issue but I don't remember anymore how and why. (I might've modified the locale for other reasons.) It's the most obvious reason for the issue described by you, especially if you work on a German computer. Which S/W gets which locale in Windows (and how to change this) is another topic I once failed to solve satisfyingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Details:**

The issue with loading a `double` variable to a `cv::Mat<double>` object has to do with a localization issue of the installed Ubuntu-16.04 OS. Due to the PC being configured in Germany, regardless the fact all parameters were set up to mimic the EN-standards on install, the PC still set its numeric, currency, time etc. interpretation to DE-standards.

This means, parsing a `double` variable from an external file will cause the OS to mistake the EN-standard decimal place, which is a period (.), for the DE-standard thousandths separator. This results in a truncation of the fraction portion of the `double` variable!

**The Solution:**

Using the Ubuntu-16.04 OS, this can be solved through changing the system locales from within the terminal. Opening the terminal, and entering the `locale` command will give the user a list of the lingual standards used for the system localization interpretations, as such:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
...
```

Changing the `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_NUMERIC`, and `LC_MEASUREMENT` tags to `en_US.UTF-8` solved the issue on my side. This can either be done through the terminal, with the following commands:

```
sudo update-locale LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
```

Or in a text editor of your choice, editing the `/etc/default/locale` file with root privileges. Once the file has been updated, make sure to reboot to finalize the changes!

A great big thank-you to @Scheff for their insight on the matter. I doubt I would have solved this without their suggestion! Much thanks, such wow!

Comment: Nitpicking: _passing a double variable to another variable_ This is bad wording. A `double` encodes the floating point value binary. There is no localization issue - never. The localization comes into play whenever a string is converted to `double` (or vice versa). In your case, this probably happens when the config file is parsed. However, the solution is correct. Btw. you can change the locale in your program as well: [setlocale()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale).

Comment: ...but C++ streams manage their own locale: [ios::imbue()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/imbue). Though, if setting the env. var. `LC_NUMERIC` did help, I would wonder when `std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");` before parsing the config wouldn't work as well.